# Why isn't pwdReset automatically set when pwdMustChange is true?

Tags: openldap, password-policy

Every other directory server, i.e. [Oracle's](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19424-01/820-4809/first-login-policy/index.html) will automatically set `pwdReset` to `TRUE` if `pwdMustChange` is defined in the policy:

> When a user's password is changed by another user, such as a password administrator, `pwdReset` is set to `TRUE`.

On the other hand, [OpenLDAP doesn't](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ape/ppolicy.html), despite the documentation:

> 5.2.13  pwdMustChange
>
> This attribute specifies with a value of "TRUE" that users must
>   change their passwords when they first bind to the directory after a
>   password is set or reset by a password administrator.  If this
>   attribute is not present, or if the value is "FALSE", users are not
>   required to change their password upon binding after the password
>   administrator sets or resets the password.  This attribute is not set
>   due to any actions specified by this document, it is typically set by
>   a password administrator after resetting a user's password.

As I understand it, this should be enforced i.e. by the ppolicy overlay. I understand the *how*, what I don't understand is the why. Is there a specific reason OpenLDAP is like this?

Comment: The linked schema documents but does not include the `pwdReset` attribute.  Have you modified your schema to include the attribute?

Comment: @BillThor -- Have you ever used the ppolicy module? pwdReset is  a virtual attribute defined by the modules internal schema. If you open the compiled module in an editor or look at the source code, you would see it.

Answer (score 1):

OpenLDAP doesn't *because of* the documentation. The OpenLDAP documentation you quoted explicitly states that it *isn't* automatic and must be set *by an administrator:*

> This attribute is not set due to any actions specified by this document, it is typically set by a password administrator after resetting a user's password.